# Updating UI constantly in Xamarin PLC

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, xamarin

My problem is to update my UI constantly in my **Xamarin PLC project**. I first tried it with threads (`System.Threading.Thread`), but this option is not available on a portable class (I also think of a `BackgroundWorker`, but I think this isn't available either). The content of the update comes from an `HTTP request`, so I have to use async. My next step was to use Tasks, but I don't get it. So I need a way to run an async method once a second, while the page is shown.
How can I do that?

Comment: Share the code with the community with which you are facing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy.

```
private async Task DoWork() 
{ 
    while(!stoppped) 
    {
        await YourFunction();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

`stopped` is just a class variable, you can use to cancel the function. Later, you could have a look at `CancellationTokens` and `CancellationTokenSource` to replace the `stopped` variable by a more sophisticated cancel mechanism.

If you have a very complex logic that uses threads, than you can convert your PCL into a .netstandard 2.0 project. This new library type supports these functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Threading.Timer` if you put shared code in `NetStandard` instead of `PCL`. The sample code is:

```
 Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
    {
      Task.Run(async () =>
      {
             await YourFunction;
      });
      return true; // True = Repeat again, False = Stop the timer
    });
```